# Setting up qgis web client

Tags: qgis, qgis-web-client

I have a problem with setting up a qgis web client on remote server. I set it up on localhost and it runs smoothly, but when I done exactly the same on remote server it is just not working, even a default maps. Helloworld example is not showing up layers, and my project is working only when i exclude about 20 layers, and by the way all styles are crashed. I could not find an issue, and exacly the same projects and many more runs great on localhost.

It is link to remote server: 185.25.148.67/qgis-web-client/site/index.html

**EDIT:**

I noticed that on localhost server sends POST requests and on remote server it is always a GET request. I think that could be the issue, since request to display all layers in GET method would be too long. But i still couldn't figure out how to enforce POST method.

**2nd EDIT:**

It is POST on remote server at the end, but it still doesn't work, here is link to the project with more layers:

185.25.148.67/qgis-web-client/site/qgiswebclient.html?map=/home/web/qgis-web-client/projects/rzgow/start.qgs

Comment: I watch your project and I can see some layers (i.e. 18 Gazociągi wysokiego ciśnienia) displaying.
Do you still have any issues?

Comment: When you check only a few layers to display, then they are displayed with wrong styles, and when you add all layers then there is a XML error.